# Add emoji to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, emoji

When I add an emoji to the database, it appears as (???)

Use this method to add and update data

```
$post_Text = 'Wh22 ';   
$update_post =$database->prepare("UPDATE `Wo_Posts` SET `postText` = :postText WHERE `Wo_Posts`.`id` = 7346"); 
$update_post->bindParam("postText",$post_Text);
$update_post->execute();
```

The result in the database was like this

```
Wh22 ????????????
```

The collation I use is  `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: What collation are you using for the table?

Comment: The collation I use is utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: It appears as question marks in the database but when you retrieve it and display it in your webpage it should still look like an emoji.

Comment: See this for more info on how "question marks" happen:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored